# PHP Error on REQUEST_URI

Tags: php

I Have the following code

```
class MyClass{ 
  protected $something = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

and I get the following error on that line:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ....

Can I do this? or what I'm doing wrong.

Best Regards,

PS: Sorry about the title, if you can find a better one, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're assigning a value to `$something` in that context, it needs to be a constant value, like a number or string. The following works,

```
protected $something = 'foo';
```

But the following does not:

```
protected $something = $foo;
```

So, if you want to assign a value to that variable, you should do it on the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
  protected $something;

  function __construct() {
    $this->something = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I will accept it in 8 minutes, 'cause I can't right now.

Comment: @Uffo: Oh! And as a suggested refactor, consider passing the URI in as an argument to the constructor. Since it just somehow seems strange to me to access a superglobal from inside a class definition. But whatever floats your boat :)

Answer (score 2):

Php won't let you do this as a definition of a property.

You can refactor it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    protected $something;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->something = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$something` doesn't expect to be filled from another variable. Try this

```
class MyClass{ 
  protected $something;
  function __construct(){
       $this->something = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
  }
}
```